# What to do with HTTP 412 (Precondition Failed) - The device is in an inactive state

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I'm getting this error whenever I try to send a push notification to a Nokia WP7 device.
Other push URI's don't return this error but with this one, every try failed, even when the phone is "awake" and with wi-fi on.

Checking MSDN docs, I came to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941100(v=vs.92).aspx

> The device is in an inactive state. The web service may re-attempt sending the request one time per hour at maximum after receiving this error. If the web service violates the maximum of one re-attempt per hour, the Push Notification Service will de-register or permanently block the web service."

Which didn't help much, as all I can do is honor the "retry after 1 hour" and try to send again.
I suspect that it can be related to the device never had a SIM card in it and therefore could not "activate" but, if this is true, why does MSPN returned a push URI for the app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ive had this problem before, I think it might be that the device has subscribed to the maximum number of endpoints, whilst your receiving a link it might not send because the Device has already maxed out its subsciptions. This is a guess blind into the dark so dont quote me on it but I am pretty sure thats all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that Microsoft generates a new ChannelUri for a device often (in the past 2 days for my 2 devices i have 5 channel uris)

It may be that a new channeluri has been generated for the device.